# How to create a registry key in 64bit view from a 32bit application, using native Windows API

Tags: windows, 64-bit, registry, 32-bit

I'm kind of a noob when it comes to windows API.

I try to create a registry key in the 64bit view of the registry, from a 32bit application using

```
System::Call "${RegCreateKeyEx}(${HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE}, 'SOFTWARE\SecureW2\Methods\Default\Profiles\26\ConfigData', 0, 'REG_BINARY', 0x00000000L, 0x0100, NULL, .r5, .r6) .r3"
```

(It's nsis scripting), but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be running into [registry redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Redirected keys are mapped to physical locations under Wow6432Node. For example, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software is redirected to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah I knew that. That's what the 0x0100 is for (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724072(VS.85).aspx)

I'm just not sure if the rest of the arguments are correct.